# layout manager for MFC dialog apps

Tags: mfc

What are the good layout managers for MFC apps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MFC dialogs, have a look at [ResizableLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resizablelib/).

Answer (score 4):

I have been using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/layoutmgr.aspx for years, it's great. I have yet to find a situation where I can't get a certain layout done with this class. The only thing I 'miss' is a visual layout designer, but I don't think there's a layout manager that has one.

Answer (score 2):

MFC resizer with anchor properties

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WndResizer.aspx

Comment: I just tried the framework, and I really don't like how it adds a message hook and tons of classes. Way too complicated code. Instead I have found that http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/dlgresizearticle.aspx is much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox_Layout.aspx

I'm looking for the same thing. I doubt Microsoft will ever come up with anything as nice as glade. It truly sucks developing for windows.

Comment: i'll check it out.
sometimes, i'm so fed up with this MFC thing.
it doesn't make life easier .

thanks.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet (just found the link), but this one looks the most promising AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this **CSizingDialog** class several times:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11538/Resize-Reposition-the-Controls-in-a-Dialog-at-your

However, are you aware that in **Visual Studio 2015** you can use the **resource editor** itself to manage control resizing? The concept is tricky to get your head around, but when you use it right you need no additional layout manager.