# Does using wxWidgets only for easier Win32 Programming make sense?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, wxwidgets

I'm writing a GUI Applikation which needs to use native Windows Controls. I'm also using a very exotic programming language with an otherwise complete runtime library. This means i have to write a GUI toolkit language binding anyway.

Without the benefits of being cross platform, C++ and having a lot of other non GUI stuff is it worth using wxWidgets? Will it save me time or will it i run into some problems resulting in the Wxwidgets cross platform abstractions.

I also tried to use MFC but the missing layout manager system (and the ones i checked after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940303/layout-manager-for-mfc-dialog-apps)) is serious problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after studying MFC and WX i went with a layer on top of MFC which eliminates the need of message maps and this strange "all has to be handled in the parent" stuff.

Took me about 15000 LOC and 6 weeks of work.

Comment: Sounds a bit like my pp2mfc product I wrote in the late nineties that let people recompile code written to the Powerplant framework against MFC. Most people don't realise that the message maps are not essential, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary compelling reason to ever use the WxWidgets library for Windows only code is you don't have a version of Visual Studio that has MFC.  For instance, if you're using Visual C++ Express Edition, or some other free C++ tool.