# Localisation not working in static control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mfc, multilingual

I am developing one Window based application, As it is window based desktop application I need to support multiple languages from Chinese to french and from Hindi(Indian) to Portuguese(Brazil) now thinks work great still there same size of text for display.But for following example,

If my one static control contain following text

**Select Output Range**   |***_****Text Box***__**|

As i am developing it in English so size of static is considered according to English text size. Thinks work great.

Now same text i converted into Chinese view of above static control is like follow,

**选择输出范围**            |***_****Text Box***__**|

I am happy as size of Chinese is less than size of English but  when i convert same text from English to french following is size of static control,

**Sélectionnez Plage de sortie**|_*Text Box***__**|

My bad size of text is increased by some worlds as we have big text on less size text, View of text will clipped like following way,

**Select Output Range**   |***_****Text Box***__**|

**Sélectionnez Plage** |***_****Text Box***__**|

In french size of text is increase ,So how to handled mismatch of text size pro-grammatically?

Comment: Try to increase size of static control dynamically..!

Comment: @Aryabhata thanks for reply but as i increase size of static control it will overlapped on textbox control..?

Comment: @nyarlathotep nop it is not because as you see problem is related to multi-language and not related to text size!!

Comment: First think is that you need to calculate size of text which is going to display on static control and according to that you need to rearrange all controls on form or may on dialog..

Comment: @Aryabhata thanks for solution but it is my first trial.As my form contain 25 controls, It is very difficult to Rearrange the controls.Any other way>

Comment: @Sankaganak well yes so it is related to the width of the multi-language string, or not? So you have to determine the string witdh of the localized string, and then use that to resize the static or possibly move around controls after that static. If that's not your problem, then please rephrase more specifically, what the exact problem is at the moment, and what you would like to happen instead.

Comment: As your question is very difficult so solution deserve dificulty. In other you can Resize the text size compress same text into specific size that you specify in English.But text will not remain in same size.

Comment: @nyarlathotep problem is somewhere around text size but as i determine the size of text and increase size on control it will overlapped text box which located just left side of static control.How to handle it?

Comment: @Aryabhata Nop It is very weird to have two static control on same form with different font..!!

Comment: @Sankaganak again you restricted..!! Then there is no solution to your problem because, Either you need to Rearrange all form according to size of each control(Which difficult according to you) or Resize the font of text which clipped..@

Comment: @Aryabhata Is there any build in Microsoft functionality to handle such kind of thinks?

Comment: are you actually searching for something which would arrange the controls automatically so that they all fit? like the layout features in C# or Java? Then maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940303/layout-manager-for-mfc-dialog-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to handle this problem. The answer depends on the way you handle the localisation in your code.

Note that some locals need the display to be inverted from left to right -> right to left (arabic...)
In this case you will have to handle cases where:

```
 Select Output Range |_Text Box__|
```

must become:

```
 |_Text Box__| <translated text into arabic or hebrew>
```

So you must be aware that translating a dialogbox is not just translating the labels. You have started noticing that because label lengthes are not the same.

If you choose to have a very simple localisation mecanism, like having a text file (containing the list of all labels) for each language, then you cannot do much more than trying to size your labels with a one-size-fits-all-languages. Dialogboxes won't look very nice in some languages. And you won't be able to use right-to-left languages. This is the quick and dirty way.

If you want to go further, the most common way is to have a resource file for each language. When your program is almost done, you have to duplicate the resource file. You have a copy for each language. You localize the whole dialogboxes, menus, etc. When you localize a dialogbox in French, you can make the label fields larger. And smaller for chinese. You can also change the dialogbox layout for arabic if you want.
Of course you have to build a version of your software for each language.

Your post has the MFC tag, so I suppose you might be interested in the MFC extension DLLs. This is the standard way for an MFC app to handle localisation. You create a DLL that only contains a resource file. If you support 10 languages, you duplicate and translate 10 resource files, and you create 10 extension DLLs. The MFC automatically load the right DLL depending on the current Windows locale. See for exemple [a sample on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14310/Library-for-MFC-applications-localization-using-re)

I would not advise you to write some code that would automatically move and resize the controls when the dialogbox is created, because this is not as easy as it seems. Unless your app is quite simple.